# Как убрать изначальное пространство div'а, когда ему задаешь position: absolute

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Я сделала контейнер с картинкой и заголовком внутри нее через position: relative и absolute, а так же подняла заголовок через bottom:0.5vh, но когда заголовок помещается во внутрь контейнера , то на его изначальном месте в потоке остается место.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда задаешь заголовку bottom: 0, то он как раз и занимает это ненужное пространство. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать это пространство?

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать отрицательный внешний отсуп.
margin-top: - 20px